# Can other Windows Servers be in the same AD domain with a Windows Essentials server?

Tags: windows, licensing, essentials-2012-r2

I understand that Windows Server Essentials 2012 R2 must be deployed as a the only domain controller in an environment. It cannot simply be used as domain-joined Windows Server running SQL or something. However, I cannot find information to confirm that the inverse is true. It's my understanding that any Windows Server Standard/Datacenter instance can be domain-joined to a domain hosted by Windows Server Essentials. Basically, so long as the Essentials server is the only domain controller, there shouldn't be a licensing problem (CALs aside) with additional Windows Servers, right?

Comment: Yes they can, although it's not very clear from any of the TechNet documentation as to the supported mix of Domain Controllers running Windows Server Essentials, Windows Server Essentials 2012 R2, Standard and Datacenter editions. If you're planning on deploying the Windows Server Essentials 2012 R2 as a DC and other servers as member servers you'll be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I understand that Windows Server Essentials 2012 R2 must be deployed
>   as a the only domain controller in an environment.

[You can have a second DC with Essentials](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/SLN288459/EN) ([as you could with SBS](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sbs/2007/10/04/debunking-myths-about-additional-domain-controllers-in-sbs-domains/)--there were [entire TechNet articles](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469602%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) about deploying your second server in an SBS environment).  Essentials has to [hold all the FSMO roles in your domain](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/dn281793.aspx), but you can indeed have more than one DC with SBS or Essentials.

(This is a common and pervasive myth.)

So yes, you can have member servers, too.

Comment: How about Essentials running Hyper-V and self-hosting an Essentials VM? I know licensing permits that, but I'm afraid to domain-join the host for fear of the Essentials host shutting down due to licensing because it's not a domain controller.

Comment: I'm pretty sure licensing's not a problem.  If Essentials is your only DC, however, you might run into issues where there's never a DC when the Hyper-V server boots.  See this non-Essentials answer here: http://serverfault.com/q/478415/174813

Comment: Can those second DCs also be Essentials edition, or must they be Standard/Datacenter? I'm guessing the answer is no.

Comment: Yeah, they need to be standard or datacenter.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

See [How to buy Windows Server 2012 R2 Essentials](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/windows-server-2012-r2-essentials/Purchasing.aspx)

> It is an ideal first server, and **it can also be used as the primary
>   server in a multi-server environment** for small businesses to protect,
>   centralize, organize, and access their applications and information
>   from almost anywhere by using virtually any device.